Line spacing in TextKit2
I'm implementing a code-like block support in the UITextView with TextKit2 and can't figure out how to set the line spacing correctly.

As you can see, the line spacing here between lines with a line break is different than the line spacing between lines of text without a line break. I want them to be equal, preferably just like the line spacing between lines of text without a line break.
I've tried setting values NSMutableParagraphStyle and have my custom NSTextLayoutFragment with values overridden, but haven't succeeded. Did anyone managed to do this?
extension RichTextEditorTextView: NSTextContentStorageDelegate {
    func textContentStorage(_ textContentStorage: NSTextContentStorage, textParagraphWith range: NSRange) -> NSTextParagraph? {
        // In this method, we'll inject some attributes for display, without modifying the text storage directly.
        // Return nil if no changes should be made
        
        guard range.lowerBound > 0 else { return nil }
        
        let paragraphText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textContentStorage.textStorage!.attributedSubstring(from: range))
        
        if paragraphText.attribute(.codeId, at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) != nil {
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0
            paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 0
            paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 0
            paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 0
            
            let textWithDisplayAttributes = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: paragraphText)
            let rangeForDisplayAttributes = NSRange(location: 0, length: textWithDisplayAttributes.length)
            textWithDisplayAttributes.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: rangeForDisplayAttributes)
            
            return NSTextParagraph(attributedString: textWithDisplayAttributes)
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}

Custom fragment:
class RTECodeLayoutFragment: NSTextLayoutFragment {
    private let _topMargin: CGFloat
    
    init(textElement: NSTextElement, range rangeInElement: NSTextRange?, topMargin: CGFloat) {
        _topMargin = topMargin
        
        super.init(textElement: textElement, range: rangeInElement)
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override var renderingSurfaceBounds: CGRect {
        let containerWidth = textLayoutManager?.usageBoundsForTextContainer.width ?? layoutFragmentFrame.width
        
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: containerWidth, height: layoutFragmentFrame.height)
    }
    
    override var topMargin: CGFloat {
        _topMargin
    }
    
    override var bottomMargin: CGFloat {
        10
    }
    
    override var trailingPadding: CGFloat {
        10
    }
    
    override func draw(at point: CGPoint, in context: CGContext) {
        context.saveGState()
        
        let borderRect = CGRect(x: leadingPadding, y: topMargin - 10, width: renderingSurfaceBounds.width, height: renderingSurfaceBounds.height + 10)
        
        context.addRect(borderRect)
        context.setFillColor(Colors.midnight.cgColor)
        context.drawPath(using: .fill)
        
        var drawPoint = point
        drawPoint.x += 10
        
        context.restoreGState()
        
        super.draw(at: drawPoint, in: context)
    }
}


Please show a [mcve].

Why you have given line spacing all properties to 0 ?

Wanted to minimize it... but it didn't have the desired effect.

Which iOS version are you testing on? It seems like it's because you're using non-zero topMargin.
